# SQLite UTF-8 inconsistency

Tags: sqlite, utf-8

I have a SQLite file, with certain pronunciations of words such as /ˈdɪkʃən(ə)ɹi/ in records. However, when I view it in any SQLite browser on a Mac, I see funny characters like /ÃËdÃÂªkÃÆÃâ¢n(Ãâ¢)ÃÂ¹i,ÃËdÃÂªkÃÆÃâ¢nÃâºÃÂ¹i/, but when I use SQLite2009 Pro on a Windows, I see the characters encoded properly.

I have also placed PRAGMA encoding = "UTF-8"; but to no avail.

What is going on here?

Comment: I used VB to write the sqlite file.

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_encoding  -- how was the database encoded at the time of its creation?

Comment: VB.NET?  Did you encode the strings as UTF8 in your client app before inserting them into SQLite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An old question now, but the browsers you were using were broken and can't properly *display* UTF-8; there was nothing wrong with your input or storage. What you got back was exactly what you'd expect to see from something that doesn't support UTF-8.

Instead, use the cross-platform [SQLite Manager for FireFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5817)